# Put positive polynomial in finite intersection of half-spaces

Tags: polynomials, linear-programming

This is a cross-posting of a MSE [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332758/put-positive-polynomial-in-finite-intersection-of-half-spaces) (which did not attract any attention there so far).

Denote by  $V={\mathcal P}_{n,d}$  the space of polynomials in $n$ variables with degree at most $d$, with rational coefficients. Thus  ${\mathcal P}_{n,d}$ has dimension $\binom{n+d}{n}$ over $\mathbb Q$ .

We can consider arbitrary intersection of closed half-spaces in $V$ : 
$N_{\Phi}=\lbrace p \in V | \forall \phi \in \Phi, \ \phi(p) \geq 0 \rbrace$, where
$\Phi$ is a subset of $V^{*}$. By analogy with [nef polygones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nef_polygon), I call $N_{\Phi}$ a nef, and I say
that it is of finite or infinite type, according to whether $\Phi$ is finite or infinite (perhaps there is a better terminology for this, that I’m unaware of).

Let $W$ denote the polynomials in $V$ that are nonnegative on ${\mathbb N}^n$. Then $W$
is clearly a nef of infinite type. I ask if for any $p\in W$, one can find a nef $W'$
of finite type, with nonempty interior, such that $p \in W' \subseteq W$.

This is possible when $n=1$ : if $p_0$ is a polynomial of degree $d$, nonnegative on
$\mathbb N$, then there is an integer $k_0$ such that all the derivatives of $p_0$
are nonnegative at $k_0$. Then, we can take

$$
W'=\bigg\lbrace  p \in V \ \bigg| \ p(k) \geq 0 \ {\rm for} \ k \leq k_0, 
p^{(j)}(k_0) \geq 0 \ {\rm for} \ 1\leq j \leq d    \bigg\rbrace
$$